# Writing ModelState valiidation code as it's own method in a controller so it can be called by multiple ActionResults

Tags: c#

Good morning,

I would consider myself a little better than a beginner with `ASP.NET`, but I have a problem that I need help with that I feel should be fairly simple, but cannot get to work.  I'm currently building a website and am looking to implement some validation rules when submitting a form.  I know that I can write the validation directly for each page I'm creating within it's corresponding ActionResult method, but I would much rather write the validation code once as it's own method within the controller and call the method within each ActionResult (for example, my ActionResult Create, ActionResult Edit, ActionResult Review) in the controller.  I want to do this to keep the code more simple and readable, especially because the validation code that I'm writing is about 500 lines long.

Here's just a portion of the code that I'm using:

```
if (ModelState.IsValidField("Name") && customerDatabase.Name== null)
   {
    ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "The customer's name is required.");
   }

if (ModelState.IsValidField("AccountNumber") && customerDatabase.AccountNumber.Length != 10)
   {
    ModelState.AddModelError("AccountNumber", "The customer's account number must be 10 digits long.");
   }

if (ModelState.IsValidField("Address") && customerDatabase.Address == null)
   {
    ModelState.AddModelError("Address", "The customer's address is required.");
   }
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Or add it as an action filter?

Comment: It also appears that you are manually validating model while attributes exist `[Required]` that would all that functionality out of the box.

Comment: Have a look at [adding validation to the model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model) article on MSDN

Comment: I know that I can do it in the model using DataAnnotations but I'd rather not go that route.  What I would like to do is use @Html.ValidationSummary("The following errors were found:", new {  @class = "alert alert-danger"} ) in the view to combine all of the errors nicely in the view.  I just think it looks better.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using validation attributes for the simple validations on the model

> In MVC, validation happens on both the client and server.
>
> Fortunately, .NET has abstracted validation into validation attributes. These attributes contain validation code, thereby reducing the amount of code you must write.

for example

```
public class CustomerDatabase {

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    //...other properties

}
```

This will also allow client side validation in a MVC View

It will reduce the amount of repeated validation needed on the server

```
if(ModelState.IsValid) {

    //...

}

return View(customerDatabase);
```

Another alternative could be to create a custom action filter to apply validation checks

```
public class ValidateCustomerModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) {
        var ModelState = context.Controller.ViewData.ModelState;
        var customerDatabase = (MyModel)ModelState.Value; //cast to expected model type
        if (ModelState.IsValidField("Name") && customerDatabase.Name== null) {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "The customer's name is required.");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValidField("AccountNumber") && customerDatabase.AccountNumber.Length != 10) {
            ModelState.AddModelError("AccountNumber", "The customer's account number must be 10 digits long.");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValidField("Address") && customerDatabase.Address == null) {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Address", "The customer's address is required.");
        }

        //...
    }
}
```

and use it on the desired actions

```
[ValidateCustomerModel]
[HttpPost]
public  ActionResult Create(MyModel customerDatabase) {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {

        //...

    }

    return View(customerDatabase);
}
```

Reference [Model validation in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: I know that I can do it in the model using DataAnnotations but I'd rather not go that route. What I would like to do is use @Html.ValidationSummary("The following errors were found:", new { @class = "alert alert-danger"} ) in the view to combine all of the errors nicely in the view. I just think it looks better.